# Dynamic tile in Fiori launchpad in HANA XSA. How?

Tags: sap-fiori, hana-xs

How can we create a dynamic tile in Fiori launchpad module in HANA XSA.
Can you please share some link or documentation.

Thanks,
Shivam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the manifest.json file of the application under crossNavigation.
The “indicatorDataSource” section makes the tile dynamic e.g.

```
…
“crossNavigation”: {
“inbounds”: {
“SalesPerformanceDisplay”: {
“semanticObject”: “SalesPerformance”,
“action”: “Display”,
“deviceTypes”: {
“desktop”: true,
“tablet”: true,
“phone”: true
},
“info”: “”,
“icon”: “sap-icon://Fiori2/F0365”,
“indicatorDataSource”: {
                          “path”: “/product_sales/resources/sap/demo/dynamictile/dynamic.json”,
                          “refresh”: “6000”,
                          “displayNumberUnit”: “%”
                  },
…
```

For more information please see the following docu here:
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/4d/2b9e3c92e54b2192f031a2941927d6/content.htm 
and here:
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_snc700_ehp04/helpdata/de/be/0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da/frameset.htm

Comment: I am following this link -
https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.02/en-US/f11324322ad445d596ec5650a6615f3c.html 
To add an SAPUI5 app to a Fiori Launchpad module. When I click on the tile the following error is thrown - "Cannot load Component.js from /1.00/resources/webapp/Component.js"
It is failing in the following step -
... "sap.platform.cf": { "uri": " " }
I have kept the resources of my SAPUI5 app inside the 'MySite' folder of the Fiori Launchpad module.
In the uri I am providing the following value -
"sap.platform.cf": { "uri": "/resources/webapp" }

Comment: Did you include “indicatorDataSource” in your manifest.json as mentioned above?
Maybe you could post your manifest.json?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am creating a separate question for this since I cannot post the entire details in the comments section. Providing the link to the new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099501/add-sapui5-application-to-fiori-launchpad-module-in-hana-xs-advanced-failed-to . Kindly provide your inputs since I am not able to figure out the solution to this problem for quite some time now. Thanks.